# How to do a proper For loop with ssis tasks

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, variables, ssis

I'm working with SSIS extensions in Visual Studio and I'm trying to iterate over a source (a SQL table) and transform each row (two columns contained) into parameters and then do flow task inside the for loop with these parameters. How can I do that? How should I do it?
Right now my loop is iterating 3 times (cause I have 3 values in the column) but I don´t know how to store each row in a variable/parameter to send it to the data flow inside the loop task.
Thank you!

Comment: Give this one a read: http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/loop-through-ado-recordset-in-ssis.html

Comment: I have reached that point, the thing is that I want to pass the values inside my objet variable to a data flow and i dont know how to access them or just call them

Comment: From the last bit under "Step 2" - Create Loop": _"On next page, Variable Mapping, here we can setup variables using inside loop. You select variable (if it doesn't exist yet you can create it from here) and specify which column value will be inserted into by Index number. First column in resultset is 0, second is 1 etc. "_

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but how I said I  already followed the guide, and yes, the loop is iterating but I want to know each row inside the column I'm setting as variable (how you quoted) and I don´t know how

Comment: what you gonna do with that variables? if you want to create script task than you can assign that variables as read only variables in the script task. if you want to use the variables as parameter for sql task then you can assign the variables as parameter mapping.

Comment: I want to pass them to a task flow, simply generate colums with the correspondent value and finally create a table with that columns. But I'm generating the table with an empty column. I can see in the variable dashboard how the variables are iterating throught the values that I want to see in my final column but they arent inserted finally

Comment: I have solved it: It was the data type of the output of the agregation column task, I changed it from unicode text to flow of unicode text (I thought first that It might be like that because I was working with variables) and my variables were shown in my table. Thank you all!!